# Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

I write chrome extension that should notify about the Twitch stream.
It works well as html page(main.html), but doesn't work as extension.

And i got error code:
"Refused to load the script 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/x3n1tr0n_?client_id=666&callback=jsonp1423306529793' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".

manifest.json

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "name" : "CS:GO Server Status", 
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [ "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/*" ],
  "description" : "Dedicated CS:GO server status checking and user notification.",
    "icons": { "32": "on.png",
             "32": "off.png",
             "128": "logo.png" },
  "browser_action" : {
 "default_title" : "CS:GO Server Status Checker", 
        "default_icon" : "logo.png"},
  "background" : { "scripts":["check.js","jquery.js"] }
  

}
```

main.html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="check.js"></script>
```

check.js

```js
setInterval(ping,1000);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () 
{
 ping();
});

function ping() 
{

 
var user_name, api_key, twitch_widget;
user_name = "x3n1tr0n_";
api_key = "666";
twitch_widget = $("#twitch-widget");
twitch_widget.attr("href","https://twitch.tv/" + user_name);

$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user_name + '?client_id=' + api_key + '&callback=?', function(data) { 
  if (data.stream==null)
  {
  alert('Offline');
  }
  else
   {
    alert('Online!!!');
     }
});

}

ping();
```

Comment: It's guiding you to `eval`. Maybe the jQuery code is executing an `eval` that is deemed unsafe. Try to do a xhr without jQuery.